# RecyclerView items disappearing on changing view type

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with 2 view types of different heights.
The one with greater height almost cover ups the whole screen. 
The default viewtype for item is the smaller one and on clicking it I change the view type to the larger one and call notifyItemChanged for that item.

Now, lets assume I have 5 items all with small views and all of them are visible on screen. As I click 3rd item it converts to the larger one. and only 3 items are visible ie 1st, 2nd and 3rd one. Now as i scroll down, I don't see the 4th and 5th item. But as I scroll up and then scroll down again the 4th and 5th item appear.

Any explanations for this behavior and how to fix it??

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if(items.get(position).isExpanded())
        return ITEM_EXPANDED;
    else
        return ITEM_COLLAPSED;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    switch (viewType){

        case ITEM_COLLAPSED:
            return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.collapsed_item,null),items);
        case ITEM_EXPANDED:
            return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.expanded_item,null),items);

    }
}
```

and this is the method in the view holder class for changing view type

```
     void onViewChanged(){

        int currentPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            items.get(currentPosition).setExpanded(!items.get(currentPosition).isExpanded());

                notifyItemChanged(currentPosition);
            }
```

Comment: cau please share your code? Also try giving "wrap_content" to height

Comment: do not ASSUME stuff. show us your code so we can check it for your problem

Comment: This happens because of `recylerView` scrapping and reusing the view. Please share your adapter class then i will be able to help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I've added

`android:clipToPadding="false"`

to the recycler view and everything works fine now